# Unable to send Watch Connectivity messages from a Dynamic Notification Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, watchos-2, watchconnectivity

I writing up this message because we encounter a weird issue while mixing **Dynamic Notification Controller** and **Watch Connectivity** calls.

You can find our sample project where we reproduced the problem here : https://gitlab.6minutecanoe.com/baptiste.leguelvouit/watch-connectivity-issue

The issue seems to be related to the `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method of the `NotificationController` class. If we override this method, and if we try to send a **Watch Connectivity** message in the `handleActionWithIdentifier` through the `ExtensionDelegate` class, the Watch app gets stuck unless we press the **Digital Crown button**.

This is really strange because if we don't override this method, everything works just fine. We also try to directly return `WKUserNotificationInterfaceTypeDefault` in this method but nothing changed.

Does anyone get this problem?

Thanks.

**Steps to Reproduce:**
Launch the sample project on a real device (iPhone + Watch) and send a remote notification with a custom category to its specific device token. When clicking on the custom action button, the problem appears.

**Version:**
Apple Watch 38mm on watchOS 2.0.1 (13S428) + iPhone 5S on iOS 9.1 (13B143)

**Configuration:**
The problem occurred especially when we try to use a **Dynamic Notification Controller** that returns `WKUserNotificationInterfaceTypeCustom` in its `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding after seeing your code is , what you are trying to do is that on receiving of push notification on `watch`....you are sending a message back to your `iPhone` app when user tap on `notification` action? right?Instead of handling action notification action in `ExtensionDelegate` class,implement the

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification withResponseInfo:(NSDictionary *)responseInfo completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler
```

method in your `AppDelegate` and then test it.